# Error when using Facebook to log in to AWS Cognito

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

My partner and I are having an issue when we use Facebook to log in to Cognito.

When we use a Facebook account that is NOT a developer, the login flow works without issue.

However, when he or I log in, we see the error message below.

```
Invalid Scopes: openid. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions
```

We have the following scopes set up in Cognito:

OAuth 2.0

Allowed OAuth Flows

- Authorization code grant
- Implicit grant

Allowed OAuth Scopes

- phone
- email
- openid
- aws.cognito.signin.user.admin
- profile

NOTE: This only happens for developers specified in the Facebook Developer portal. It does not affect end users.

Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Did openid get deprecated and replaced by something? If I remove openid from the scope, I no longer can get the IdToken from Cognito.

Comment: Facebook’s OAuth implementation never had a permission named `openid`.

Comment: Be that as it may, openid is an option in the Cognito settings (so your comment is for the folks at Amazon, not here). Also, in February, we weren't seeing this error. Did something change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to AWS documentation *The Facebook scopes and attributes may vary with each API version, so we recommend testing your integration.* (found in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-configuring-federation-with-social-idp.html). So maybe you can check according to the api version of Facebook that you are using. In the case that you want openId (that is not the default scope for Facebook ) then, according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/ you should ask specifically for it as per this sentence *If you ask for permissions other than the default profile fields, email, or pages_show_list, you must submit your app for app review so Facebook can confirm that the app uses the data in intended ways and safeguards user privacy.*

Comment: Thanks. The confusion I had was in the scopes specified in the User Pool and the scopes specified in the Authorized Scopes. I included openid in the scopes in the Facebook config, and when I removed that, the error went away.